# Multiview app memory leak warning.

Tags: objective-c, ios4, memory-management

I made a multiview app based on this [Tutorial](http://vimeo.com/8930397).Here is my code in the **appdelegate.h**

```
@class Disclaimerviewcontroller;

@interface GAINSAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    Disclaimerviewcontroller *firstview;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain )Disclaimerviewcontroller *firstview;

-(void)switchview :(UIView *)view1 toview:(UIView *)view2;
@end
```

and in the ".m" i have the following

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    Disclaimerviewcontroller *aview = [[Disclaimerviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"Disclaimerviewcontroller"bundle:nil];
    self.firstview = aview;
    [_window addSubview:aview.view];
    [aview release];
    return YES;
}

-(void)switchview :(UIView *)view1 toview:(UIView *)view2{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
    [_window addSubview:view2];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

and the dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc
{   [firstview release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

from there on when ever I want to switch to another view I use the following code

```
-(IBAction)switchtodisclaimer2:(id)sender{

    GAINSAppDelegate *delegate = (GAINSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    Disclaimerviewcontrller2 *disclaimview2 = [[Disclaimerviewcontrller2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Disclaimerviewcontrller2" bundle:nil];
    [delegate switchview:self.view toview:disclaimview2.view];


}
```

just like in the tutorial. but when I did an analyze test. xcode warned be of possible memory leak in the above code. so i added (in the above case) `[disclaimerview2 release];`and when I run the program I get `EX_BAD_ACCES` error. I thought since it was initwithnibname it was an autorelease ?. I'm confused now. the tutorial doesn't seem to be addressing this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for memory ownership is this :

> If your method name starts with 'alloc', 'init', 'copy', 'mutableCopy' or 'new' they you are responsible for releasing it, either with `release` or with `autorelease`

So yes, you do have a memory leak so you should release 'disclaimview2' with `[disclaimview2 release]`

However, the reason that you are crashing is because of another bug somewhere in your code.

If you are going to pass it into your delegate, *your delegate should retain it* - otherwise, the delegate will try to use it at some point in the future but will have been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer in some cases can warn even if there isn’t one. It would be better if you ran the app through the Instruments application and then see if there actually is  memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the method `initWithNibName` returns and object without autorelease. You should use
 `[[[Disclaimerviewcontrller2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Disclaimerviewcontrller2" bundle:nil] autorelease];`.

Alternatively, you can save `disclaimerview2` as property and free the memory in the dealloc method (without using autorelease).

Hope this helps.